# Rubbish in char

Tags: c++

I got a problem with that code:

golf.h:

```
const int Len = 40;

struct golf
{
    char fullname[Len];
    int handicap;
};

void setgolf(golf & g, const char * name, int hc);

void setgolf(golf & g);

void handicap(golf & g, int hc);

void showgolf(const golf & g);
```

golf.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "golf.h"
using namespace std;

void setgolf(golf & g, const char * name, int hc)
{
    int i=0;
    while(*name != '\0')
    {
        g.fullname[i] = name[0];
        cout << "g.fullname[i]: " << g.fullname[i] << ", name[0]: " << name[0] << endl;
        name++;
        i++;
    }

    g.handicap = hc;
    cout << "setgolf: " << g.fullname << ", " << g.handicap << endl;
}

void setgolf(golf & g)
{

}

void showgolf(const golf &g)
{
    cout << "showgolf: " << g.fullname << ", " << g.handicap << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "golf.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    golf selby, higgins, sullivan;

    setgolf(selby, "Mark Selby", 10);
    setgolf(higgins, "John Higgins", 20);
    setgolf(sullivan, "Ronnie O'Sullivan", 30);
    showgolf(selby);
    showgolf(higgins);
    showgolf(sullivan);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Problem is ..... when i run in Debug mode i got result:

```
showgolf: Mark Selby, 10
showgolf: John Higgins=@, 20
showgolf: Ronnie O'Sullivanvr, 30
```

Just 1st enter to setgolf() and showgolf is correct, in rest adds some rubbish at end of chars ...

But when i run in Release mode i got diffrent result:

```
showgolf: Mark Selby,ujs,uČjć'ł, 10
showgolf: John Higgins■   js,uM@, 20
showgolf: Ronnie O'Sullivan, 30
```

Just last enter to setgolf() and showgolf() is correct, in rest adds some rubbish at end aswell.

Can someone explain me why that rubbish are and where they from?

Comment: In `void setgolf(golf & g, const char * name, int hc)` when you reach the end of name then you have to set the remaining characters of `fullname` to zeroes.

Comment: Use std::string instead of char arrays. And since you use Qt you also could use QString.

Comment: Those are snooker players, not golf.

Comment: If you are going to use character arrays, you will need to use the `str*()` functions, such as `strcmp` and `strcpy`.

Comment: OT: you are programming like it's done in C. In C++ setgolf would be the constructor of class golf.

Comment: You need to copy the nul-terminator char as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting random garbage characters because `fullname` is not null terminated. In order to print using `std::cout` then `fullname` must be null terminated. Please see the below code -

```
void setgolf(golf & g, const char * name, int hc)
{
    int i=0;
    while(*name != '\0')
    {
        g.fullname[i] = name[0];
        cout << "g.fullname[i]: " << g.fullname[i] << ", name[0]: " << name[0] << endl;
        name++;
        i++;
    }

    g.fullname[i] = 0; //null termination

    g.handicap = hc;
    cout << "setgolf: " << g.fullname << ", " << g.handicap << endl;
}
```

Another option to print character by character of `fullname` till the length of `fullname`.

Comment: Thank you a lot ;) Everything work well now :)

Comment: @morti This wouldn't have been a problem in the first place if you used `std::string`, so keep that in mind. C-style strings are *extremely* thorny and very difficult to use.